# Deploy Angular 7 Application to Azure Web App

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have found a lot of articles on how to deploy angular app to azure web app. However none working. I found a solution where I create a Visual Studio Web Project, copy dist files from Visual Studio Code Project and deploy from Visual Studio. However that is not really effective. I guess the web app need some web.config files .. Isen't there a better way than this? I would prefer to deploy directly from Visual Studio Code without having an asp.net web project. If I just deploy I get following error when navigating to the page:

```
Cannot GET /
```

In this article it seems like all you need is a higher version of NodeJS:

https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-an-angular-app-from-visual-studio-code-to-a-1

But dosent seem to work.

Comment: What server do you use express.js/webpack? You need to configure the web server.

Comment: Check this link maybe can help you https://www.webcodegeeks.com/javascript/angular-js/deploy-angular-app-visual-studio-azure/

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The article you link to is the article I followed. Dosent work. The node version on the azure web app is now 10.10 and same on my local machine. Locally I uses the node server through CLI ng serve.

Comment: https://sajeetharan.com/2020/02/14/deploy-angular9-app-to-azure-with-github-actions/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want to deploy a static website based on Angular 7 without any node serverside codes on Azure WebApps.

I will follow the Angular offical [`Getting started`](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) to explain the deployment steps.

1. On my local machine, the steps will create `my-app` project, which include `npm install -g @angular/cli`, `ng new my-app`, and `cd my-app`. I will skip these steps about edit and `ng serve` to build directly as the step below.
2. I will get a `dist` directory under the `my-app` path when just do `ng build`. Next, I only need to copy all files under the `dist/my-app` directory to the directory `wwwroot` of Azure WebApp via Kudu console or FTP or other ways. Then, it works when browser the url `https://<your-website-name>.azurewebsites.net` like the figure below.
   [image]
3. If you want to show your angular app via the website host with path, such as `https://<your-website-name>.azurewebsites.net/docs`, you can build your app via `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href` that will create a `docs` directory under `my-app` path, and you directly copy the `docs` directory into `wwwroot`, then it works on `https://<your-website-name>.azurewebsites.net/docs` from your browser as the figure above.

Here is my screenshot of my `wwwroot` path in Kudu.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, very detailed! I will test later, highly appreciated!

Comment: Check also here, a step by step tutorial to deploy an Angular web app from VS Code to Azure with the new Static Web Site feature. https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/static-website/getting-started